# Listview Scroll super smooth in phone not the same in tablet

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `listView` that scrolls really smooth with my animation in place,it looks very neat. But when i run it on a tablet the `listview` takes forever to move. I have used a twopane view for tablet, but the `listview` component are the same i use the same adapter, the same `Async task`, my adapter implements the holder pattern. Now i'm not sure what is wrong.

Please let me know if there is some specific part of the code i should post. As i'm bamboozled as to what to post.

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: What do you use AsyncTask for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of thousands `onMeasure` methods in layout. Make items bigger (to fill screen with one item) and you see the performance from phone. Try to use fixed width and height in layout or use `match_parent` not `wrap_content`

**EDIT**

I solved the problem with

```
android:persistentDrawingCache="animation"
android:animationCache="true"
android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
android:drawingCacheQuality="low"
```

in layout container and with

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ... />
```

in `AndroidMainfest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the number of items that fit the tablet is bigger than the number of items visible on the phone.
Also, I don't know what you are animating, but if you animate a lot of items (which are also bigger on the tablet) this could cause bad performance.

Comment: i am animating the list Items. I don't think that will cause the kind of delay i am experencing. Anyway tried it out by commenting out the list amimation,still the same.